# symfony xml configuration repeated array nodes

Tags: xml, symfony, configuration, components

I'm trying to parse and validate an xml configuration file with Symfony configuration component.

Config file is like the following:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <root>
        <description>description</description>
        <rows>
            <row name="name">
                <type>text_validated</type>
                <label>Name</label>
                <font>opensans</font>
                <fontSize>9</fontSize>
                <maxLength>95</maxLength>
                <editable>false</editable>
            </row>
            <row name="name2">
                <type>text_validated</type>
                <label>Name 2</label>
                <font>opensans</font>
                <fontSize>9</fontSize>
                <maxLength>95</maxLength>
                <editable>false</editable>
            </row>
        </rows>
    </root>`
```

With an arbitrary number of  tags (1 or more than 1).
And I would like to achieve a result like the following:

```
array:2 [
    "description" => "description"
    "rows" => array:2 [
        "name" => array:6 [
            "type" => "text_validated"
            "label" => "Nome Hotel"
            "font" => "opensans"
            "fontSize" => 9
            "maxLength" => 95
            "editable" => false
        ]
        "name2" => array:6 [
            "type" => "text_validated"
            "label" => "Nome Hotel2"
            "font" => "opensans"
            "fontSize" => 9
            "maxLength" => 95
            "editable" => false
        ]
    ]
]
```

Would it be possible using Symfony configuration component?